# Understanding fully qualified names in Perl packages

Tags: perl, package, namespaces

I'm trying to understand some code from [CGI.pm](https://metacpan.org/dist/CGI/source/lib/CGI.pm#L3651), specifically:

```
package CGI::MultipartBuffer;
....
$MultipartBuffer::INITIAL_FILLUNIT ||= 1024 * 4;
...
$INITIAL_FILLUNIT = $MultipartBuffer::INITIAL_FILLUNIT;
```

What I need to know is the fully qualified names of `$MultipartBuffer::INITIAL_FILLUNIT` and `$INITIAL_FILLUNIT` as in my interpretation they should both be `$CGI::MultipartBuffer::INITIAL_FULLUNIT` but I must be mistaken as otherwise why would the second assignment statement be needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$INITIAL_FILLUNIT` isn't declared, so it's a package variable.<sup>[1]</sup> Since the current package is `CGI::MultipartBuffer`, it refers to `$CGI::MultipartBuffer::INITIAL_FILLUNIT`.

This means that

```perl
$INITIAL_FILLUNIT = $MultipartBuffer::INITIAL_FILLUNIT;
```

means

```perl
$CGI::MultipartBuffer::INITIAL_FILLUNIT = $MultipartBuffer::INITIAL_FILLUNIT;
```

---

1. This would be forbidden by `use strict;`.

Comment: Thanks - what does $MultipartBuffer::INITIAL_FILLUNIT mean though?

Comment: I'm using perl -d and Dumper on the symbol table, and it looks like $MultipartBuffer::INITIAL_FILLUNIT actually means $main::MultipartBuffer::INITIAL_FILLUNIT.  I was assuming that it meant $CGI::MultipartBuffer::INITIAL_FILLUNIT

Comment: Re "*What does $MultipartBuffer::INITIAL_FILLUNIT mean though*", It's a variable. What do you mean?

Comment: Re "*it looks like $MultipartBuffer::INITIAL_FILLUNIT actually means $main::MultipartBuffer::INITIAL_FILLUNIT*", Technically, yes. But only because it's also $main::main::MultipartBuffer::INITIAL_FILLUNIT, $main::main::main::MultipartBuffer::INITIAL_FILLUNIT, $main::main::main::main::MultipartBuffer::INITIAL_FILLUNIT, etc.  But really no. It's means $MultipartBuffer::INITIAL_FILLUNIT

Comment: Ok thanks - figured that out by looking at the symbol table hash. I was assuming it was in the CGI package not the main package. I have this now fixed in my dev version of Pythonizer.

Comment: I undid your erroneous edit. The packages are `CGI::MultipartBuffer` and `MultipartBuffer`. It makes no sense to use `main::CGI::MultipartBuffer` and `main::MultipartBuffer`. It makes even less sense to be inconsistent.

Comment: Ok no worries. What confused me was the author of CGI both using package CGI::MultipartBuffer (declared) and MultipartBuffer (undeclared)- made me think the second one was a subpackage of CGI instead of main.

Comment: Again, not a subpackage of main. It's `$MultipartBuffer::INITIAL_FILLUNIT`, not `$main::MultipartBuffer::INITIAL_FILLUNIT`